# Is the "keikaku means plan" meme from a real fansub?

Tags: death-note, meme

I imagine most older anime viewers are familiar with the following image, featuring Light Yagami from Death Note with his dialogue subtitled "Just according to keikaku" and the note "keikaku means plan" at the top:

[image: keikaku means plan meme]

People often claim that this is screenshotted from a real fansub of Death Note. However, my attempts to discover the fan group responsible have met in failure. On their page [Just According to Keikaku](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/just-according-to-keikaku), Know Your Meme attribute the origin of the screenshot to "a fansub" without naming any names or sourcing this claim. Other results I found with a quick Google search give no further details either.

My question is, **did this fansub really exist** or is this just a meme invented to poke fun at low-quality subs?

Comment: Something that could pose a challenge to find it in this day and age is, fansubs walk a very precarious line between existence and DMCA, so there's a very, very good chance that the group who did this is long gone and haven't left a trace.  Worse still, keeping track of who subbed what can also be a challenge if it was reuploaded somewhere else (and *they* put their watermark over the sub), which - to be blunt - wouldn't surprise me if that's what happened here.

Comment: Based on quick research, looks like it was a fansub parody: [a tweet by @kukuruyo](https://twitter.com/kukuruyo/status/1625975935559237653), but proving a negative may be difficult. (Also related: [TV Tropes - Too Long; Didn't Dub](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TooLongDidntDub))